# how to make line api bot button connect to database?

Tags: php, api

I'm creating a line bot from line api. i made button, its success but i want to make if someone click the button it will insert/update value database

heres the example of api (https://devdocs.line.me/en/#template-messages)

```html
{
  "type": "template",
  "altText": "this is a buttons template",
  "template": {
      "type": "buttons",
      "thumbnailImageUrl": "https://example.com/bot/images/image.jpg",
      "title": "Menu",
      "text": "Please select",
      "actions": [
          {
            "type": "postback",
            "label": "Buy",
            "data": "action=buy&itemid=123"
          },
          {
            "type": "postback",
            "label": "Add to cart",
            "data": "action=add&itemid=123"
          },
          {
            "type": "uri",
            "label": "View detail",
            "uri": "http://example.com/page/123"
          }
      ]
  }
}
```

help me?